# can't complete the cell borders in apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, border

I am putting borders in styling our excel file. I'm using propertyTemplate of Apache POI.

I tried to change the numbers, but I can't successfully fill the borders. There's still gaps. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWfg.png)

My code goes like:

```
pt.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(7, 10, 4, 10),
                BorderStyle.MEDIUM, BorderExtent.ALL);
```

What can I change to achieve in filling all the borders?

Comment: Your showed code uses `PropertyTemplate` to draw all borders in range `E8:K11`. There your linked picture shows no gaps in the borders. So your code doesn't fit to the picture. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AxelRichter i meant to fill the gaps from Beginning to Subtotal. What range should i put there? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Row and column indexes used in [CellRangeAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html) are 0-based as all other row and column indexes in `apache poi` too.

So your `new CellRangeAddress(7, 10, 4, 10)` is the range from row index 7 to row index 10 and column index 4 to column index 10. That is the range `E8:K11`.

Probably you meant to set all borders in `B7:K12`. That would be `new CellRangeAddress(6, 11, 1, 10)`.

Complete example to test:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.PropertyTemplate;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class ExcelDrawingBorders {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ExcelDrawingBorders.xlsx") ) {

   int startDataRow = 6; // row 7 (index 0-based)
   int endDataRow = 11; // row 12 (index 0-based)
   int startDataColumn = 1; // column B (index 0-based)
   int endDataColumn = 10; // column K (index 0-based)

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   for (int r = startDataRow; r <= endDataRow; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = startDataColumn; c <= endDataColumn; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue(cell.getAddress().formatAsString());
    }
   }

   PropertyTemplate propertyTemplate = new PropertyTemplate();
   propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(startDataRow, endDataRow, startDataColumn, endDataColumn), 
    BorderStyle.MEDIUM, BorderExtent.ALL);

   propertyTemplate.applyBorders(sheet);

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }
 }
}
```