# How to add border cells in Java with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

0

I am trying to add border in the excel using below Java code using apache poi. It's taking hours of time to get the border applied. I know i have used loops because the border has to be made based on it as there is a requirment.Are there any other ways to reduce the time consumption ?
x1,x2 will keep on changing based on the iteration

```
static int x1 = 1
static int x2 = 0
XSSFCellStyle style = report.createCellStyle();
style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
PropertyTemplate pt = new PropertyTemplate();  
for (Object cellValues : rowsSet) {
    x2 = x2 + rowsSet.size();   
    pt.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(x1, x2, 1, 1),  
    BorderStyle.MEDIUM, BorderExtent.OUTER);   
    x1 = rowsSet.size() + 1;
    pt.applyBorders(sheet);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add border cells using Java in shorter time span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487679/how-to-add-border-cells-using-java-in-shorter-time-span)

Comment: The question title is very confusing. Please edit it to focus in the problem at hand instead of giving instructions to readers.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It doesn't help to delete/re-ask a question. Rather provide (on top of your code) your observations and expectations. Also, given that your deleted question had a solution, but you insisted to "use a loop": consider that you _might_ be stating an [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/364505). Also, given a certain size of your sheet, I'd expect any loop to take a while.

Comment: Note: After I wrote above comment, I found an issue in your code and described it in my answer. However, as you just ask to "add borders", but with no explicit description of _which cells you'd like to apply them to_, I stopped with the description of the issue in your code. You'd still have to make the proper correction yourself, as the question doesn't describe what you want to achieve (other than "borders"). Running your code in a debugger (and inspecting the values) _really_ would help you understand your own code.

Comment: Your question appears to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77487679/230513); instead of deleting it, please [edit] the question to elaborate on why you can't use the [approach suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77487872/230513).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_can't complete the cell borders in apache poi_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72125841/230513).

Answer (score 1):

What do you want your loop to do? Have you debugged through your code?

Given

```
for (Object cellValues : rowsSet) {
    x2 = x2 + rowsSet.size();   
    pt.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(x1, x2, 1, 1),  
         BorderStyle.MEDIUM, BorderExtent.OUTER);   
    x1 = rowsSet.size() + 1;
    pt.applyBorders(sheet);
}
```

and a size of your rowSet of 100, your x1 and x2 values will look like these in your iterations:

| Iteration | x1 start | x1 end | x2 start | x2 end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 101 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 101 | 101 | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | 101 | 101 | 200 | 300 |
| 3 | 101 | 101 | 300 | 400 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 99 | 101 | 101 | 9900 | 10000 |

Is that expected? (Assuming: No)

Given that you address a `CellRangeAddress(x1, x2, 1, 1)`, this can easily go out of hand, and generate a humongous spreadsheet - thus take its time (but not provide the output that you expect)

On top, note [the interface of](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html) `CellRangeAddress(int firstRow, int lastRow, int firstCol, int lastCol)` - especially the parameter names. `firstCol` and `lastCol` are always 1 in your case. `firstRow` is always (apart from the very first iteration) 101, while `lastRow` goes steeply up